# Getting “#N/A” error when using importhtml formula

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I was trying to import a table from hket website to run some analysis of my own.

When I used: `=importxml("http://www1.hket.com/finance/chart/industry-index.do","//*[@id='eti-finance-chart-table']")` which represents the link to the site, I am getting the "N/A" error.

The `importxml` works fine with gurufocus site.

Can you help me out? I haven't been able to figure out what the issue could be.

from what I understand, hket doesn't use HTML or XML format for their table. If that is the case, is there a script I can use in Google Sheets that will let me extract data from hket?

Answer (score -1):

you can see the culprit if you run this formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www1.hket.com/finance/chart/industry-index.do", "//*")
```

[image: 0]